# How to make a fetch call within another fetch and add the data to an array using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, fetch

I am trying to fetch the name, height and movie title of each person using an API and fetch. Firstly, I fetch from the people endpoint and get the array of results. I create an array and obj so I can eventually loop through the array and output to a table. I loop through the results to get the first film URL from each person then fetch on that URL. I create a key/value pair for the name, height and title and then push to the array. The problem I having is that when I console out the array, it displays an array of 10 empty objects. I am not sure why this doing this. I have had many problems and logically can't solve it. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/') 
    .then(res => res.json()) 
    .then(json => {
        let results = json.results
        let arr = []
        let obj = {}
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            let firstFilm = results[i].films[0]
            fetch(firstFilm).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                obj['name'] = results[i].name
                obj['height'] = results[i].height
                obj['title'] = data.title
            })
            arr.push(obj)
        }
        console.log(arr) // [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ]
    })
```

Comment: "10 empty objects" it is even worse: you have the same object present in array 10 times ;). `Promise.all` is your friend.

Comment: Please don't totally change a question after other people have already answered it - you invalidate their answers by doing that. If you have another question, create a new post.

Comment: Why dont you just make one request handle it all? Fix your query to get the additional information from the initial results from one endpoint.

Comment: Could you please supply an answer. I tried that and again gave me an empty array @Jake

Comment: I would console log your results and make sure you are getting data in the first place...Secondly I would console log out firstFilm in your second fetch call and make sure that contains a valid url to make a fetch call from

Answer (score 2):

Using `Promise.all` should do the trick.

```js
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    return Promise.all(
      json.results.map(
        item => fetch(item.films[0])
        .then(x => x.json())
        .then(film => ({
          name: item.name,
          heihgt: item.height,
          title: film.title
        }))))
  }).then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch to async/await and you're code will get easier to follow IMO

```js
async function doTheThing() {
  const res = await fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/');
  const json = await res.json();
  const result = await Promise.all(
    json.results.map(async(item) => {
       const res = await fetch(item.films[0]);
       const film = await res.json();
       return {
         name: item.name,
         heihgt: item.height,
         title: film.title
       };
    })
  );
  console.log(result);
}
doTheThing();
```

Working Example (url changed for sample data)

```js
async function doTheThing() {
  const res = await fetch('https://greggman.github.io/doodles/test/data/films.json');
  const json = await res.json();
  const result = await Promise.all(
    json.results.map(async(item) => {
       const res = await fetch(item.films[0]);
       const film = await res.json();
       return {
         name: item.name,
         heihgt: item.height,
         title: film.title
       };
    })
  );
  console.log(result);
}
doTheThing();
```

Comment: Uhhh, `.map()` does wait for a promise or get the return value from it.   This won't work.

Comment: It will work just fine. map doesn't need to wait for a promise. It just needs to return an array of promises for Promise.all which is what the code above does. [Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/vp2c0kfq/)